# how to call javascript function from action function?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, conga, conga-composer

found error after clicking button'Genrate invoice'

> Error:: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token **

how to resolve this??

visual force page::

```
<apex:page standardController="Payment__c" extensions="Search" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"  id="pageid" docType="html-5.0">

<apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" onclick="GenerateInvoicePay()"/>
                    <apex:actionFunction name="GenerateInvoicePay" action="{!GenerateInvoice}" oncomplete="openConga('{!Payment_Id}');" reRender="pageid"/>

<Script Language="JavaScript"> 
var stringvalue='{!Payment_Id}';
             function openConga(stringvalue) 
             { 
             GenerateInvoicePay();

                alert('payment Id2');

                window.location.href = '/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&'+
                                       'id='+{!Payment_Id}'&'+
                                        'serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_370}';
               } 

  </Script>
```

controller::

```
      public Id Payment_Id {get;private set;}
            public Id  PaymId{get; set;}

            public PageReference GenerateInvoice() 
        {
        selectedEsr = new List<Payment__c>();
        for(wrappayment wp : paymentList)
            {
                if(wp.selected == true) 
                {

               Payment_Id=wp.pay.id;
                system.debug('Payment_Idline517'+Payment_Id);
                payid=Payment_Id;
                 system.debug('payidline520'+payid);

    }
    }

    return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are not constructing the URL properly. You need to  make few changes for this to work.

- You are calling the `actionFunction` again from javascript method which takes your code into recursion which is not needed.
- There is no need of `actionFunction` as you can call your javascript method from oncomplete event of `commandButton`.

This is the working code, see if it can help you

```
<apex:page standardController="Payment__c" extensions="Search" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"  id="pageid" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" action="{!GenerateInvoice}" oncomplete="openConga('{!Payment_Id}');" reRender="pageid"/>
        <script Language="JavaScript"> 
            //var stringvalue='{!Payment_Id}';
            function openConga(valueFromParam) { 
                //GenerateInvoicePay();  //comment this as you don't need it.
                alert(valueFromParam);
                window.location.href = "/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&"+
                "id="+ valueFromParam + "&serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_370}";
            } 
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @@Vijay Ganji..As per your suggestion i modified but issue occured                                                                                                    
 issue::1) after click on the button , conga page is not coming even alert is also not showing.    please reply as soon as possible

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check now

Comment: @@ Vijay Ganji  Still facing same issue

Comment: @@Tushar Sharma,@@Vijay Ganji, how to call Conga Page for selected ID? please help me..

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check now, also make sure that the development mode is switched off before testing this.

Comment: @@Vijay Ganji...   valueFromParam?? which value i have to put here in valueFromParam?

Comment: That will be passed from your command button. Please check the commandbutton oncomplete code as well.

Comment: @@Vijay Ganji Thanks for your help got conga page.

Comment: That's great !!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling recursive. You need to comment the second `actionfunction` calling from your JavaScript method.

```
<apex:page standardController="Payment__c" extensions="Search" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"  id="pageid" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" onclick="GenerateInvoicePay()"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="GenerateInvoicePay" action="{!GenerateInvoice}" oncomplete="openConga('{!Payment_Id}');" reRender="pageid"/>
<Script Language="JavaScript"> 
    var stringvalue='{!Payment_Id}';
                 function openConga(stringvalue) 
                 { 
                 //GenerateInvoicePay();

                    alert('payment Id2');

                    window.location.href = '/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&'+
                                           'id='+{!Payment_Id}'&'+
                                            'serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_370}';
                   } 


</Script>
```

So your command button wil call the `actionfunction` which in place will call the JS method. But in existing code you need to add rerender="none" in your command button. But if you want you can remove the `actionFunction` here.

This code will also work and will give you same results.

```
<apex:page standardController="Payment__c" extensions="Search" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"  id="pageid" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" action="{!GenerateInvoice}" oncomplete="openConga('{!Payment_Id}');" reRender="pageid"/>
<Script Language="JavaScript"> 
    var stringvalue='{!Payment_Id}';
                 function openConga(stringvalue) 
                 { 
                 //GenerateInvoicePay();  //comment this as you don't need it.

                    alert('payment Id2');

                    window.location.href = '/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&'+
                                           'id='+{!Payment_Id}'&'+
                                            'serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_370}';
                   } 


</Script>
```

Comment: But ID is not calling inside the conga URL       window.location.href = '/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&'+
                                           'id='+{!Payment_Id}'&'+
                                            'serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_370}';    In conga page error is coming 'The id parameter is missing.'   please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you try to replace `{!Payment_Id}'` with the `stringvalue` parameter.

Comment: @@ Tushar Sharma ..      I added this code::window.location.href = '/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&'+
                                       'id=stringvalue&'+
                                        'serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_370}';      coming error:: Not authorized. 
The stringvalue parameter ID is not valid. Ensure that the parameter ID is 15 to 18 alpha-numeric characters and does not include spaces. in conga page

Comment: @Juhi.L Can you try `window.location.href = '/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&'+ 'id='+stringvalue+'&'+ 'serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_370}'`

Comment: @@Tushar Sharma,Vijay Ganji  on visualforce page for "invoice" object there is a button genrate pdf. After selecting the record and After Clicking on the genrate pdf button,directly the pdf should be downloaded and email should be sent. In the backend I have created  a Conga button on the "invoice " object and add template id there in the conga button. Now my requirement is "When the we selects the record from visualforce page and click on the button
Then a invoice pdf is generated and stored in the system ready to download and send to the customer via email"help me..

Comment: please suggest something...